# Laravel 4 Mail failing using transactional email provider

Tags: php, laravel, email, sparkpost

I am working with Laravel 4 at the moment, I am wanting to link in a transactional server, Sparkpost does everything I need it too, but I am having trouble implementing it, whenever I use Mail::send(), I get the following error,

> Type swift.transport is not bound.

I cannot find any reference about this error anywhere online, does anyone have any experience of implementing Sparkpost and Laravel 4, this is my mail config file,

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'sparkpost',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => 'smtp.sparkpostmail.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => 587,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => array('address' => 'technical@xxxxxxx.com', 'name' => 'xxxxx noreply'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => 'STARTTLS',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => "SMTP_Injection",

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => $_ENV['sparkpost_secret'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail "Pretend"
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

);
```

Anyone any ideas where I have gone wrong, I am using Sparkpost via, this package,

https://packagist.org/packages/clarification/sparkpost-laravel-driver

I have added the Services to my service.php file, and also added the package to my providers array.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to make it work

1. In your app/config/mail.php change encryption to "tls"
2. Run a composer update